# Http request sent an empty body

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post

This is the code for my post request:

```
Future<User> createUser(String name,String username,String email,String password, String passwordConfirm, String role) async {
  final response = await http.post('http.register.com',
      body:jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'name': name,
        'username': username,
        'number': email,
        'password': password,
        'passwordConfirm':passwordConfirm,
        'role':role,
      })
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load request');
  }
}
```

The problem is once I sent it, the body goes empty to the API.How could I solve it?

```
_futureUser = createUser(_namecontroller.text ,_usernamecontroller.text,_email.text ,_passwordcontroller.text ,_passwordConfirmcontroller.text, _role);
```

I put some more codes,I think it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to `post` function document https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/post.html 
If `body` is `String` , the `content-type` of the request will default to `"text/plain"`. 
If `body` is `Map` , the `content-type` of the request will default to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`. 
You can set header to `application/json`

code snippet

```
http.post(url,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: body
```